# power supply circuit design concept

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design

I want help in calculating the value of the smoothing capacitor in the power supply circuits which  located after the rectifiers
please  through an illustration as figure and example for one  full wave -half wave rectifier
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Given Q = C * V, we can take the derivative, assume zero dC/dV, and arrive at:

- I = C * dV/dT

Now let I = 1 amp, dV = 1 volt ripple, and dT = 1/120 seconds

C =  I * T / V

C = 1 * (1/120) / 1 = 1/120 = 8,333 microFarads

Comment: Thank you Can you explain what was mentioned through an illustration? I did not understand why the 1/120 was chosen